# What is the royal cypher printed on the UK budget box?

Tags: united-kingdom, government, monarchy, heraldry

The dispatch box used by the Chancellor of the Exchequer bears a royal cypher for Elizabeth II on it:

[image: George Osborne with the budget box in 2014]

This differs from the usual cypher used in that the numerals " <sub><sup>**II**</sup></sub> " appear below the initials rather than in between them.

To make matters more intriguing, the previous box used for more than 150 years beginning with William Gladstone [also bears a royal cypher](https://www.flickr.com/photos/hmtreasury/4720955639) that is difficult to read given the box's condition but must surely also be Elizabeth's cypher, with numerals interscribed not below, since it appears to be an addition made some time since [Geoffrey Howe appeared with it](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/mcs/media/images/77528000/jpg/_77528779_77528778.jpg) in the 80s.

Where does this rarer variant of the cypher come from and why is it used?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I hope these resources will assist someone else's research. I suspect, based on [postalmuseum](https://www.postalmuseum.org/blog/royal-cypher-appearances/), that the cypher is less standardized than you assume.  [Red box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_box_(government)) also indicates that the design is bespoke, which would grant an additional degree of freedom. Finally [historianruby](https://historianruby.com/2018/04/01/royal-ciphers-on-postboxes-a-brief-guide/) shows that there seems to be permissible variations in location of numbers

Answer (score 2):

**The new red box, as modelled by George Osborne in the OP's picture**

It appears to be Queen Elizabeth II's coronation monogram:

[image]

https://i.ucoin.net/coin/2/482/2482448-2/guernsey-50-pence-2003.jpg

[image]

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/variants-of-the-royal-cypher-of-hm-queen-elizabeth-ii--172684966949598149/

[image]

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Royal_Monogram_of_Queen_Elizabeth_II_of_Great_Britain.svg

I do not know why this variant was used. As MCW pointed out in the comment, red boxes are bespoke and the decision may have been purely aesthetic (but I speculate).

**Gladstone's red box**

The [description on the website of National Archives](https://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C640145) does not mention the cypher, but I think it is Queen Victoria's monogram. Click on the link below the picture and zoom in. The sharp downward point of the V is visible.

[image]

https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/news/2016/10/29/4357291_Britains_Chancellor_of_the_Exchequer_Darling_holds_Gladstones_old_Budget_box_outside_11_Do_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqqVzuuqpFlyLIwiB6NTmJwfSVWeZ_vEN7c6bHu2jJnT8.jpg

For comparison:

[image]

https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/7UAAAOSwrDxfu57u/s-l500.jpg
(from https://www.ebay.com.my/itm/1888-Book-Owned-by-HRH-Queen-Victoria-Special-Prize-Binding-ROYAL-Cypher-VR/143861341886)